# filter an array of objects if condition is not null

Tags: jquery, arrays

Lets suppose we have an array of objects like this:

```
var people = [
    {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, 
    {first: "Alan", last: "Doe"}, 
    {first: "John", last: "Black"}
];
```

How can we filter this array in jQuery if only one condition is selected by the user, for instance he want´s only the Doe last names (using a select form with two fields: first name, last name), hence the first name is not selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aghosh08/bL8bxk02/

Comment: There is one problem. As suggested in the question there is a form selection with two fields - first name, last name. The selection is parsed as an array of two elements. If just one filed is selected (for instance the last name), the other field is passed as null. What would the filtering look like with one field null or not?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested use `.filter()` to filter the array:

```js
var people = [
    {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, 
    {first: "Alan", last: "Doe"}, 
    {first: "John", last: "Black"}
];

var filteredPeople = people.filter(function(person){
   return person.last === 'Doe'
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredPeople, 4, 0));
```

Comment: There is one problem. As suggested in the question there is a form selection with two fields - first name, last name. The selection is parsed as an array of two elements. If just one filed is selected (for instance the last name), the other field is passed as null. What would the filtering look like with one field null or not?

Answer (score 0):

already answered in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590901/2409250

```
var result = people.map(function(a) {return a.first;});
```

this is what you would do

Comment: this isn't a filter that does what op is asking.